# Create Primary key in sql server

Tags: sql-server

I have one table in sql server having duplicate ID,but I can not delete those duplicate records .Now the requirement is to create the primary key on that column which is having duplicate data. Is there any way to create the primary key without changing the data.

Comment: No. The whole point of any key (primary or secondary) is that it can be used to *uniquely* identify rows. So your requirements "create the primary key (*on the existing column*)" and "without changing the data" are in opposition. You cannot satisfy both

Comment: Primary key witness uniqness, so you can't create primary key on dublicate data column. Instead you need to create a new column with identity on it, on this column you can create primary key.

Comment: No I have to create the primary key on that column only so that it will bypass the existing record while validating the primary key and for the new record it will validate and give the error if any duplicate record comes.

Comment: do it with trigger instead of  and temp table that hold all distinct id.if inserted in temp then print "id already exists..." else ...

Answer (score 1):

No, there is no way to a add a PRIMARY KEY constraint to a column that already has duplicate values.

[Creating and Modifying PRIMARY KEY Constraints:](https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms181043(v=sql.105).aspx)

> When a PRIMARY KEY constraint is added to an existing column or
> columns in the table, the Database Engine examines the *existing* column
> data and metadata to make sure that the following rules for primary
> keys:
>
> - The columns cannot allow for null values.
> - *There can be no duplicate values*.
>
> If a PRIMARY KEY constraint is added to a
> column that has duplicate values or allows for null values, the
> Database Engine returns an error and does not add the constraint.

In case `ID` column is incremental, then a possible workaround is to add a *unique filtered index*:

```
CREATE UNIQUE INDEX AK_MyUniqueIndex ON dbo.MyTable (ID)
WHERE ID > ... max value of existing ID here
```

This way, uniqueness will be applied only to newly added records.

Comment: The same thing we can do it in oracle with No validate syntax and same kind of thing we are looking into sql server.

Comment: @prashant_ora I don't think this is possible in SQL Server. You only can do this with `CHECK` constraints.

Answer (score 0):

I know this is old, but, had this idea that I wanted to share:

1. Step 1. Add a non-nullable int column with a default value that can
   be 0
   Optional step. Update that column to a 1, so you are able to
   identify this existing records afterwards.
2. Step 2. Update column in all existing rows where there are duplicates with a standard rownumber() using a combination of unique columns or all columns.
3. Step 3. Define primary key with your ID column first (So, it is
   indexed first), then add Step 1 column.

And you are done and with a special column that can helps identify the duplicates easily and the new records which will be all marked as 0, but the best practice would be to add a character or number to all Ids if possible and standardize (This approach helps to do that afterwards), or use something like by year sequence, etc.